# Rake db:create continues to use /tmp/mysql.sock despite my.cnf settings

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm on a Mac and used brew to install an updated MySQL. In an effort to streamline my local database creation, I took the password off my local root user (I know, I know), and after creating a new Rails app (`rails new myapp -d mysql`), should just be able to run `rake db:create`, right?

However, despite having `/etc/my.cnf` set to define the standard mysql.sock location...

```
[mysqld]
socket=/usr/local/var/mysql/mysql.sock

[client]
socket=/usr/local/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

... Rails still won't use the newly defined `mysql.sock` file on a `rake db:create`:

```
rake db:create
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "encoding"=>"utf8", "reconnect"=>false, "database"=>"delayed_jobs_development", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"root", "password"=>nil, "host"=>"localhost"}, charset: , collation:
```

Running `mysqladmin variables` lists the correct socket file location, as does `mysql --help`. I've restarted the MySQL server and even recreated the Rails app.

So my question: What else could be defaulting the socket file to `/tmp/mysql.sock`, or is there an alternate, preferably global, config file where I could specify its location that the rake task will honor? Could the rake task be calling a different commandline MySQL tool that uses a different config file?

Obviously, I could either create a symlink from the `/tmp` location to my real location, or edit my `database.yml` file to refer to it. I understand how to get Rails to talk to the DB server correctly, but the point is to have the proper defaults set up once, so any future Rails app I create locally is good to go without extra edits (/tmp/mysql.sock gets cleared on reboot).

In fact, I'm not even sure why it's trying to connect via the socket file at all, since my `database.yml` file tells it to use the hostname:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: myapp_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the MySQL documentation says, `/tmp/mysql.sock` is the default location for the socket file. This is also what rails defaults to (more below).

As you mentioned, you can always set the socket (the one you configured and that is returned by `mysqladmin variables`) explicitly in your [database.yml](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#configuring-a-mysql-database) file:

```
socket: /usr/local/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

I think the connection is made via the socket file as you set `host: localhost`. If you change that to `127.0.0.1`, the [connection should by made over TCP/IP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html).

I found rather old information (a [really old version of the mysql adapter](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5b3f7563ae1b4a7160fda7fe34240d40c5777dcd/activerecord/lib/active_record/vendor/mysql.rb) and a [blog entry from 2007](http://log.gmarik.info/2007/01/learning-rails-issue-1.html)) which implies that the `MYSQL_UNIX_ADDR` environment variable is used in resolving the socket. Also see this [comment on GitHub](https://github.com/tmtm/ruby-mysql/issues/12#issuecomment-777857) by the developer of Ruby/MySQL, in which he says to set the `MYSQL_UNIX_PORT` variable instead. A third env variable is `MYSQL_SOCKET` mentioned in the [source of the Ruby/MySQL](https://github.com/tmtm/ruby-mysql/blob/master/spec/mysql_spec.rb) connector.

```
export MYSQL_UNIX_ADDR=/usr/local/var/mysql/mysql.sock
export MYSQL_UNIX_PORT=/usr/local/var/mysql/mysql.sock
export MYSQL_SOCKET=/usr/local/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

I do not know if these variables get evaluated somewhere along the way. Still, you could try them out.

Right now, rails [`mysql_adapter.rb`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb) says that the configured `socket` is used and that it defaults to `/tmp/mysql.sock` (set in [`app_generator.rb`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb)). No other locations seem to get checked. I did not found anything else in the default `Ruby/MySQL` adapter used by rails.

So basically – without being an expert on this topic – I don't think there is a way to set a global default location for the MySQL socket file that gets evaluated by rails or the used default adapter.

Comment: First off, thanks for the in depth answer and research you did on this. So nice to see you took the time to poke around. I tried all three environment variables, and MYSQL_UNIX_PORT did the trick. This resolves my proboem, and I'm going to suggest that app_generator.rb include /usr/local/var/mysql/mysql.sock for brew MySQL installs as well.